# vert.x JdbcClient not working while using event bus

Tags: vert.x

i want to create jdbc connection after received the message, but its not working in my code,

```
final JDBCClient jdbcClient = JDBCClient.createShared(vertx, new JsonObject()
  .put("url", "**********")
 .put("driver_class", "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver")
  .put("max_pool_size", 30)
  .put("user", "*****")
  .put("password", "*****"));

 MessageConsumer<JsonObject> consumer = eventBus.consumer("sms.msg");
request = new JsonObject();

consumer.handler(message -> {

  jdbcClient.getConnection(conn -> {
    if (conn.failed()) {
      System.out.println(conn.cause().getMessage());
      return;
    }else {
      System.out.println("connection Successful");
    }

    request = message.body();
    System.out.println("\n\n***** MySql Update Verticle Start ***** \n Request received : \n " + request.toString());

    final SQLConnection connection = conn.result();
    connection.query("select * from employee where id=222", rs -> {
      if(rs.succeeded()) {
        for (JsonArray line : rs.result().getResults()) {
          System.out.println(line.encode());
        }

      }else {
        System.out.println("error query");
      }

      // and close the connection
      connection.close(done -> {
        if (done.failed()) {
          throw new RuntimeException(done.cause());
        }
      });
    });
  });


});
```

in my logger like that

2019-12-31 13:39:58,629 INFO  [MLog-Init-Reporter] (Slf4jMLog.java:212) - MLog clients using slf4j logging.

Comment: Can you give more details.

Comment: without consumer its working correctly, but after using event bus its not working